# Replace nil elements in array with values from two other arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have three arrays: `g`, `a` and `b`. `g` has two groups of one or more consecutive `nil` values. The first (second) group contains `a.size` (`b.size`) `nil`s. I wish to replace each `nil` in the first (second) group with the corresponding element of `a` (`b`). For example, if:

```
g = [1, 2, nil, nil, nil, 3, nil, nil, nil, nil]
a = [55, 45, 56]
b = [100, 200, 300, 400]
```

I wish `g` to become:

```
 [1, 2, 55, 45, 56, 3, 100, 200, 300, 400]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: result = [1,2, elements of a, 3,elements of b]

Comment: The result of what? Why not just write `g` out "correctly" the first time? What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I edited to clarify. Please re-open. Downvoters: please consider removing your downvote ( unless, of course, you are displeased with my edit).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `[]=` method can assign like this, one of its variants is

```
foo[insertion_point, length] = values
```

(there is also a version that takes a range instead of this pair of values)

```
g = [1,2,nil,nil,nil,3,nil,nil,nil,nil]
a = [55,45,56]
b = [100,200,300,400]

g[2, a.size] = a
g #=> [1, 2, 55, 45, 56, 3, nil, nil, nil, nil]
g[6, b.size] = b
g #=> [1, 2, 55, 45, 56, 3, 100, 200, 300, 400]
```

As long as the gaps are the same size as the arrays you are inserting, you wouldn't need to do anything about the nils

Answer (score 1):

```
g.map!{|e| e || a.shift || b.shift}
# => [1, 2, 55, 45, 56, 3, 100, 200, 300, 400]
```

Comment: I like this, but would prefer `c=a+b; c.map { |e| e.nil? ? c.shift : e }`. `nil?` in case any elements equal `false`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Right. That depends on what the OP has. As always, you are the best supporter of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I set up an enumurator and pull items from it whenever necessary. Either of these extends easily to more input lists

```
itr = (a + b).to_enum
g.map!{ |e| e.nil? || itr.next }
```

or in this case `[a, b]` can be replaced with a more general tree

```
itr = [a, b].flatten.to_enum
g.map!{ |e| e.nil? || itr.next }
```

Comment: Interesting use of an enumerator. Similar to @sawa, but non-destructive of `a` and `b`. (Of course, sawa could operate on copies of `a` and `b`). Maybe `a+b` rather than `[a,b].flatten`. You could use `to_enum` instead of `each`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, I would prefer if there was a version of flatten that returns an enumerator. It seems overkill to define one for this question where it's not apparent whether the overhead of copying is significant or not.

Comment: Yes, plus you are creating two temporary arrays (to be garbage-collected) in order to create the enumerator whose purpose is to avoid creating an array. :-)

Answer (score -1):

I think you can do it in this way:

```
g.insert(6, *b); // inserts b into 6 index
g.insert(2, *a); // inserts a into 2 index
g.compact! // removes the nil elements
```

Note that we are inserting in the reverse way so as to not disturb the indexes.

Comment: The inserts would have to be done in reverse (eg. 6 then 2) with this method or else the second insert index would be incorrect because the array has already had elements inserted at a prior location.

Comment: @user2864740 yeah, thanks for pointing out. Didn't cross my mind, my bad. Thanks anyway :)